# Find the sum of the digits using a loop and a function

Tags: python-3.x

I am using a function to get the number from user, and I am trying to use a while loop to separate the digits of a number. And I am trying to add the digits of the number. But my code runs infinitely.
Example : 2345 -> 15

```
def sumDigits(n):
    sum=0
    while len(str(n))>0:
        a = n%10
        n = n//10
        sum += a
    return sum
print(sumDigits(2345))
```

Expected: 15

Actual: I had to shut down the jupyter kernel to stop the while loop.

Edit 2: Removed the updated code as it was answered by the community.

Comment: Are you sure these digits are single digits and they cannot be '2', '34' and '5' as per your example?

Comment: 2345 is a single number with 4 digits. The program should do 2+3+4+5.

Comment: `len(str(n))>0` how is this going to be false?

Comment: @VidhyaSagar. I have added the solution.

Comment: All you basically have to do to fix it is to find the correct condition for your loop. `n > 0` should be enough.

Comment: @njzk2, I get it now. That's why my loop was running infinitely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This condition `len(str(n))>0` can never be false as long as `n` is an integer, because `str(0)` is `'0'`, which has a length of 1.

You need to change the looping condition to exit where there is no more digit to sum, which happens when `n` reaches 0:

```
def sum_digits(n):
    total = 0
    while n > 0:
        a = n % 10
        n = n // 10
        total += a
    return total
print(sum_digits(2345))
```

Note: `sum` is a built-in in python, so naming a variable `sum` is not advised. Also, method names usually are written in snake_case, so `sum_digits` is recommended.

Answer (score -1):

```
def all_sum(number):
    total = 0
    if number > 0:
    for e in str(number):
        if e.isdigit():
            total += int(e)
        else:
            pass
    return total
a = all_sum(567897)
```

This should do your work. Instead of doing two arithmetic operations to 'fetch' the digits, better to change the argument to string and just use each digit. Its faster and saves memory (though it's not too memory consuming).

Comment: input is an int, apparently.

Comment: `n = n//10` in the question for example. You're changing the signature of the function the OP is trying to write.

Comment: Thats just how you format the parameter. Be it integer or str, it is easier to get the single digits out. I have edited the code to take the parameter as int.

Comment: `;` is not python. the `return` statement is incorrectly indented. 'int' object has no attribute 'isdigit'